# Install crystal report runtime in azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, crystal-reports, azure-sql-database

When I try to publish the project in Azure cloud it shows that it could not load file or assembly log4net. As I was running few days ago, suddenly it had stopped working. Now I am trying to install crystal report runtime in azure cloud. I am running this on the 64 bit windows and the software that's installed on the system is also a 64 bit application. I have tried to find the same problem that I have been facing for a couple of days but still did not manage to find it.

Failed to create ServiceDefinition.csdef file in visual studio
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have stuck on this problem for like 7 days and finally solved it by creating a virtual machine and install crystal report runtime on the vm. Also i have published the project in the vm. good luck...